# Anaconda/Conda on OS X 11 -- Broken Jupyter Notebook with DEFAULT installation

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I am running the latest Anaconda on OS X 11 and cannot for the life of me figure out how to get jupyter notebook to run. It ends in this error:

```
% jupyter notebook
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/opt/anaconda3/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 7, in <module>
    from notebook.notebookapp import main
  File "/usr/local/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 85, in <module>
    from .services.contents.manager import ContentsManager
  File "/usr/local/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/services/contents/manager.py", line 17, in <module>
    from nbformat import sign, validate as validate_nb, ValidationError
  File "/usr/local/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nbformat/__init__.py", line 32, in <module>
    from .validator import validate, ValidationError
  File "/usr/local/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nbformat/validator.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .json_compat import get_current_validator, ValidationError
  File "/usr/local/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nbformat/json_compat.py", line 10, in <module>
    import jsonschema
  File "/usr/local/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jsonschema/__init__.py", line 32, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import get_distribution
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pkg_resources'
```

I have tried fresh installs of both miniconda and anaconda without success. Nothing seems to work.

It baffles me that a *default* install of anaconda (no updates, no extra packages, nothing) is broken. Do these people even test their stuff?

Any solutions or suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you installed `xcode command line` tools?

Comment: Yes, installed and up-to-date